# rename s3 bucket files with title that has user details such as name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to rename files in s3 bucket and was wondering if there is a way to rename the files by somehow querying an SQL script so that it can return the information and use that to update the name of the file.

```
for example a file in s3 
00123456789.word

//Some SQL Script
select u.name, a.address from users u
left join address a
on u.id = a.id
where u.id = 00123456789

-- returns George Washington / 111 abc street

Then somehow use this data returned from running the SQL script to rename the file

george_washington_111_abc_street.word
```

I will most likely need to use the CLI since there are many files and renaming them manually seems irrational.

Is this possible to do or is there some other method?

EDIT:
Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to somehow program or script this activity.

The way I would do it is:

- Run the SQL query to **return the three columns** (id, name, address) for ALL rows
- Load the resulting data into an **Excel spreadsheet**
- Add a column that makes a 'rename' command like:

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucketname/00123456789.word s3://bucketname/george_washington_111_abc_street.word
```

You can use Excel formulas to convert the name and address to lowercase and replace spaces with underscores.

Then, use **Copy Down** to create the `aws s3 mv` command for every row. You can then **copy those commands into a text file** and run the file from the command line. It will individually rename every object.

This might not work if you have a *huge* number of objects (eg tens of thousands). In this situation, you might need to do it programmatically.

Comment: What is the rename column you are speaking about? Do you mean to add that to a table? 
Also what is the option to do it programmatically?

Comment: My recommendation is to create an Excel formula that outputs an `aws s3 mv ...` command like the one shown above, given the data extracted from the database. If you wish to do the 'rename' programmatically, then your program will need to `CopyObject()` and then `DeleteObject()` since Amazon S3 does not actually have a 'rename' command.